# Camel Rest DSL Response Codes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a route builder that looks as follows:

```
.post("/myEndpoint")
    .type(MyObject.class)
    .to("bean:myListener?method=create")
```

I would like this to return a 201 Created HTTP Response Code, at present its returns a 200 OK.

Is there a way to do this in the RouteBuilder without having to forward any results onto a separate service class and then manually set the code on the Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We managed to get it to work by doing the following -

```
.post("/myEndpoint")
    .type(MyObject.class)
    .route()
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE,simple(HTTP_CREATED))
    .to("bean:myListener?method=create")
.endRest()
```

Comment: What's the fully-qualified package for `HTTP_CREATED`?

Comment: It is just a constant we defined e.g.

protected static final String HTTP_CREATED = "201";

Comment: Yes, agree, it's a constant. For me works with: constant(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED.value())

Answer (score 0):

See the header section here http://camel.apache.org/constant.html for setting headers.. You should be able to set the http response code and body directly.